# Measuring Size Of output JSON of REST API?

Tags: rest-api

I need to get my size of the JSON going as response.I am using recent REST API's  of salesforce using apex annotations like @HTTPGET .Can someone please point me out how will i see the size of output JSON using REST EXPLORER of workbench or someother tools if needed .

Comment: Do you mean the length of the JSON string itself? Or are you asking about the number of objects or fields in the response or something?

Comment: No i know the limit of response is 3MB .I want way of measuring the response size .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
   @HttpGet
    global static List<Account> getAccounts() {
       List<Account> accounts = [select id, name from Account];
       System.debug(JSON.serialize(accounts).length());
        return accounts;
    }
```

The code above just does the JSON serialisation that SF is going to do automatically, but does it before hand and logs it out to the debug log.   It's a bit wasteful and really only for informal checking

Realistically, I would use Curl from the command line as documented here:

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_rest_code_sample_basic.htm

Comment: Perfect awesome

Answer (score 3):

You can look at the Content Length HTTP header to get the length of the response body in bytes. In Workbench REST Explorer, click on Show Raw Response to see the headers on the right hand side of the output.

Comment: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: 
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Wed, 03 Oct 2012 15:27:28 GMT ..................        The content length is missing in workbench in the header

Comment: Please note that the following headers aren't allowed:
cookie
set-cookie
set-cookie2
content-length
authorization
If any of these are used, an Apex exception will be thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this

convert the responsebody to a string ( RESPONSE Body (corrected ) is a blob use .tostring())

```
string name = 'hello this is a test message to find bytes of the string ';
blob encode = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(name);
system.debug('%%%%' + encode.size());
```

DEBUG LOG :

```
Execute Anonymous: string name = 'hello this is a test message to find bytes of the string';
Execute Anonymous: blob encode = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(name);
Execute Anonymous: system.debug('%%%%' + encode.size());

10:51:47.092 (92605000)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[1]|name|"hello this is a test (36 more) ..."
10:51:47.092 (92619000)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[2]
10:51:47.093 (93020000)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[2]|system.EncodingUtil.base64Decode(String)
10:51:47.093 (93165000)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[2]|system.EncodingUtil.base64Decode(String)
10:51:47.093 (93469000)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[2]|encode|BLOB(33 bytes)

10:51:47.093 (93676000)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[3]|System.debug(ANY)
10:51:47.093 (93693000)|USER_DEBUG|[3]|DEBUG|%%%%33
10:51:47.093 (93702000)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[3]|System.debug(ANY)
```

Comment: This will work i am sure.good solution

Comment: Why is the response a blob?  Why base64 decode a string?

Comment: steven response is not a blob the response body is a blob http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_restresponse.htm